# Difference Symmetric of two closed sets are disconnected

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A$ and $B$ be closed subsets of $X$.   Prove that if $A$ does not contain $B$ and $B$ does not contain $A$, then $(A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ is disconnected.

Comment: The $\TeX$ symbol for "set-theoretical minus" is $\setminus$, typed as $\text{\setminus}$. I will go ahead and edit your post.  **lol** actually never mind, I saw you didn't use ANY $\TeX$.

Comment: And $\cup$ is `\cup` rather than $U$

Answer (score 1):

$A$ does not contain $B$ and $B$ does not contain $A$ implies that $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$ are not empty.

Let $C_A$ be the complementary space of $A$ in $X$, it is open. $B\setminus A=B\cap C_A$, thus $B\setminus A$ is open in $(B\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus B)$. $A\setminus B$ is also open in $(B\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus B)$. Since $(B\setminus A)\cap (A\setminus B)$ is empty, you deduce that $(B\setminus A)\cup (A\setminus B)$ is the union of two non empty disjoint open subsets, so it is not connected.

The function defined on $f:(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)\rightarrow \{0,1\}$ whose restriction to $A\setminus B$ is $1$ and whose restriction to $B\setminus A$ is $0$ is continuous.

Comment: Cloud you explain what do you mean by complementary space

Comment: @Gob: Tsemo just means $X\setminus A$.